# Place two lines separated by CR/LF on the same row where a certain symbol exists

Tags: notepad++, newline

I have searched for this numerous times to no avail, and I am sure it will help others. What I am trying to achieve is, using notepad++, place two lines together if separated by CR/LF and a certain separator.

Example:

```
some text [CR/LF]
/explanation
/explanation 2
some other text [CR/LF]
/explanation 3
```

TO

```
some text /explanation /explanation 2 [CR/LF]
some other text /explanation 3 [CR/LF]
```

I know how to use Extended and \r\n replacement to add thing at the end of a row, or replace something, I basically want to replace the CR/LF that is preceeded by backslash into a CR so I can then replace that with emptystring and then it will be on the same line.

Thank you for all your involvement in this,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

Find what: `\R/`
Replace with: `/`

Comment: M42 Thank you, I was now editing my question as solved as I have reached the same conclusion :) I was trigger happy and did not test that before.

Comment: @user2795105: You haven't to edit your question a solved, just accept the answer if it solved your problem.